# Удалить незаполненные числа в массиве при выводе

Tags: c#

Я бы хотел, чтобы последняя строка вывода

( Console.WriteLine("Массив из положительных чисел: " + string.Join(" ", narray)); )

выглядела так: Массив из положительных чисел: 3 5 6 7 9
но она выглядит так: Массив из положительных чисел: 3 5 6 7 9 0 0 0 0

То есть, я бы хотел убрать из вывода нули, потому что это не очень красиво.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[,] array = new int[3, 3]
        {
            {-1,-2,3 },
            {-4,5,6 },
            {7,-8,9 }
        };
        int[] narray = new int[array.GetLength(0) * array.GetLength(1)];
        Console.WriteLine("Массивный массив, с которым будем мы работать: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                Console.Write(array[i, j] + "\t");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        int x = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                if (array[i, j] > 0)
                {
                    narray[x] = array[i, j];
                    x++;
                }                    
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Массив из положительных чисел: " + string.Join(" ", narray));

    }
```

Спасибо за Вашу помощь!

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", narray.Where(x => x != 0)));`

Comment: Используйте для `narray` не массив, а `List<int>`.

Comment: `Array.Resize(ref narray, x);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Я бы сделал просто так:

```
Console.WriteLine(
    "Массив из положительных чисел: " +
        string.Join(" ", array.Cast<int>().Where(n => n > 0)));
```

[Проверка](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgNAJiA1AHwAICYCMBYAUKgBgAJVMA6AGQEsoBHAbjzxuAG0YBdIgQzDG4CeRALxEoAUwDuRFqwDMMInI54A3niKatm1QFpMMXehhyiAXxgbtWvQBYYAVhgA2c5dzWbAdkMAOGACc5nhmjLh4pAEAFFaaAESAOCCADCCAgiApgBwggEwgROmA7CBEgPwggHwggNwgRYBsIOmAQiCArCAlgDIggLwggNIggKIgRIDiIOkpdSBEcUSIsdakBGQAUgD2NFEDcYq8/AJkAMLcAM7AADwsAHxRAJRkAOoAFuJg4lFQIrtiRHcEB89hQA=).

---

Разоблачение магии: все массивы, даже многомерные, наследуются от типа `System.Array`, который реализует, среди прочего, нетипизированный `IEnumerable`. Реализация `IEnumerable` перечисляет все элементы массива в «плоском» виде (то есть в виде длинного одномерного списка). Чтобы перейти к типизированному `IEnumerable<int>`, можно применить `Cast<int>`, и отфильтровать нужные элементы при помощи `Where`. А для `string.Join` материализация не нужна, он будет вполне доволен, если на вход подать `IEnumerable<int>`.

Трюк с `Cast` не нужен для одномерных массивов, т. к. они дополнительно реализуют типизированный `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: А можно просто использовать OfType, если тип известен. И кастовать не надо, что бы избежать потери производительности

Comment: @Sam_Fisher: А как, вы думаете, будет выполняться `OfType`, если не проверкой типа? Она не особо отличается от преобразования типа (cast).

Comment: Не особо отличается, но более безопасный вариант.
В Cast нет проверки типа и если тип неверный в массиве, то код упадет с ошибкой.

Comment: @Sam_Fisher: С моей точки зрения, `Cast` как раз более безопасный вариант. Если вы знаете, что в массиве инты, и вдруг `Cast` падает с исключением, это значит, что вы не понимаете, что происходит в программе, и вам лучше бы поискать причины проблемы. С `OfType` вы просто подавляете проблему, и не знаете о ней.